# Problem with Excel 365 VBA in scraping data from a website

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am somewhat skilled in using VBA, but a complete novice when it comes to scraping data from a website.  Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub test()

    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim reqURL As String

    reqURL = "https://www.xxxxx.com/options-income/signals?page=1&pageSize=40"

    XMLPage.Open "GET", reqURL, False ', "xxxxx.com", "11576"

    XMLPage.send

    If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then

        MsgBox XMLPage.Status & " _ " & XMLPage.statusText
        Exit Sub

    End If

    MsgBox XMLPage.Status & " _ " & XMLPage.statusText

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    Debug.Print XMLPage.responseText

End Sub
```

This is the result I get when I run this code:

```
<pre>
!doctype HTML>
html lang="en">
head>
base href="/">
meta charset="UTF-8">
    
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
title>xxxxxx</title>
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,500,600,700,800">

  
link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/assets/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/assets/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
link rel="manifest" href="/assets/images/favicons/site.webmanifest">
link rel="mask-icon" href="/assets/images/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  

link href="app.1484e48c09d5c2673d38.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
body>
div id="root"></div>
script type="text/javascript" src="vendor-89c02a07.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="app-ce8531bd.js"></script></body>
/html>
</pre>
```

All identifying information in the code or result has been changed.

The result is the same information that appears on the Source tab of the Edge Developer Tools (or the Chrome or IE equivalent).  What I need is the information in the "td" tags that appears on the Elements tab of the Developer Tools, but I have thus far been unable to produce that result.

I would very much appreciate any assistance you might be able to offer, and thank you in advance to those who do.  By the way, I think this is my first post to stack overflow.  So, I am not sure that I have done things properly.  Apologies, if I have not.

Comment: There are not td tags in your html code. Please post the whole html code or at least the necessary part of code as code snippet. Don't wrap the code in pre tags and don't cut off the first sign in every line. If possible post the url too.

Comment: @Zwenn: Yes, there are no td tags in the code yet because there are no td tags in the result the code produces.  The td tags are shown in the Elements page of the Developer Tools, and I need to be able to access that part of the website.  So the question is how to I get to that part of the website using the code that I have written so far?  The pre tags are not around my code.  They are around the HTML result my code produces.

Comment: Then it is most likely a page that loads dynamic content. The HTML code you have posted is only the part that is loaded first. Only the first static part of the page is fetched via an HTTP request. To load dynamic content you can use the Internet Explorer if the page is still running in this browser. Another possibility is the Selenium Framework or of course the use of another language, like Python and the Beautiful Soap Library. I can only say more if you can post the original URL.

Comment: Thanks @Zwenn for the explanation.  I have been trying to make sense of it, but I am getting no where fast.  If I use a similar code but use IE instead of XML, I get the same result.  I cannot seem to find what additional code runs to create the dynamic content you mention. I really know nothing about Python or the other programs you mention.